# How to implement a negative edge triggered D-flipflop using using level triggered D-flipflops?

Tags: digital-logic, flipflop

Say here's a **negative edge triggered D-flipflop** with its timing diagram with random binary signal.

[image]

And on the other hand, here's a **level triggered one**:
[image]

How do I **implement the negative edge triggered D-Flipflop with a Level Triggered D-Flipflop**? what should be my approach?

Comment: Look up master slave D flip flop. https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Negative-edge_triggered_master_slave_D_flip-flop.svg

Comment: the second diagram has the CLK and D signals reversed ... the CLK is yellow and D is blue